# Jaydata with WebSql, how to manage version upgrades

Tags: cordova, jaydata

I am currently using Jaydata on a PhoneGap application I am developing. Everything is working great so far. But I couldn't find a single update on how to manage upgrades to the database when I release a new version of the app.

Is there a way to run scripts depending on the version of the application?

I don't want to have to drop the changed tables everytime a new version is deployed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage DB upgrades using the API of [JayData Schema Evolutions module](http://jaydata.org/blog/schema-evolutions)

Comment: From what I understood, this is a feature that is only available for the JayData Pro version. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Correct, it's only in the Pro version